# $http.post is sending as null in console as well as in url provided

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX with Struts 2 using AngularJS</title>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("MyController",function($scope, $http) {
$scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
        $http.get("angularAction").success(
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.person = data;
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                     // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
};




$scope.postDataToServer=function(){
    /*$scope.items={"firstName":"sandeep","lastName":"suluguri"}; */
    /* var data = angular.toJson($scope.items); */
    /* var data=$scope.items; */
```

In the console its printing as null and when i get the data from angularPage even its showing as null. Is my format of writing the post method correct?

```
    $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'angularPage',
         data: {'message' : 'harsha'},
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         /*   $scope.items = data; */
           console.log(data);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // alert("Error :: "+data);
          console.log('error');
      });   
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

When I click the buttons it triggers the respective functions in the controllers.
My get method is working fine.It fetches data from that url and displays on the page

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
                <button ng-click="getDataFromServer()">
                Fetch data from server
                </button>
                <p>First Name : {{person.firstName}}</p>
                <p>Last Name : {{person.lastName}}</p>
                <button ng-click="postDataToServer()">post data to                      server</button>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need an absolute path.

Comment: share ur server side api

Comment: I didn't add any server side api @umakant Mane